# What's the error in my MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql

The following SQL statement has a syntax error according to phpMyAdmin, but I can't spot what it is. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE allocations(
`student_uid` INT unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`active` INT unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`internal_id` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT '',
`tutor_uid` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`allocater_uid` INT unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`time_created` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`remote_time` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`next_lesson` VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
PRIMARY KEY ( student_uid )
);
```

Comment: Please send the error message it helps.

Comment: Put here the complete error message.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers - it was the missing length on VARCHAR. The code now works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
next_lesson` VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
```

should be changed to

```
`next_lesson` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
```

Comment: @dorkitude my apology I did not realize you had the same answer when I hit submit

Answer (score 6):

The VARCHAR type requires a size (and it's smart to use quotes around the value), so try replacing

```
`next_lesson` VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
```

with

```
`next_lesson` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
```

Comment: @Angel.King.47 in this case it will work without quotes, but good call. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your last VARCHAR has no length.

Answer (score 0):

2 things I can think of:

1. I don't think you can set a varchar not null with an empty default, mysql might consider an empty string the same as null.
2. Set varchar fields to a string not a number, so:

   `next_lesson` VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to set a default on the primary key field since that can must be unique.